# How does updating state with useState hook in React work

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I understand how updating state using the **useState** hook in React works as follows.

1. Compare the state value to be changed with the current state value.
2. If the two state values are the same, do not re-render without changing the state value.
3. If the two state values are different, change the state value and perform re-rendering.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-fog-riyg4

But in this example, it seems to work differently.

- First rendering execute when App component is mounted.
- State value changes when button is clicked and a second rendering is executed. (Because the current state value and the state value to be changed are different.)
- When you click the button again, the state value does not change but rendering occurs. ***-> Why is this happening? I didn't expect rendering because the two state values were the same.***
- When you click the button a third time, the state value does not change again, but this time the component does not re-render. This is the behavior I expected to happen after the second click.

Comment: The rendering doesn't occur to me. Why do you need to know the implementation at this level?

Comment: Just calling `setState`, regardless of value, triggers a re-render. You can prevent this by `shouldComponentUpdate()`

Comment: @Chris this is not true, on the 3rd and 4th click the rerender is not triggered

Comment: There is no comparison between current and previous state during `setState`, it just updates the state with the given value and calls a re-render. Even if the state value is the same, it will still re-render

Comment: @SmailGalijasevic, can you elaborate why?

Comment: @Chris because on the each next click after the second click the rerendering is not triggered even we are still calling the setState handler

Comment: @SmailGalijasevic I think there is a confusion about whether we are talking about `setState` (which is what the post says) or `useState` (which is what the snippet uses). They behave differently.

Comment: So I actually looked at the code sandbox, they aren't using `setState`, they're using hooks. @OP, state in components and state in hooks aren't the same. With `setState`, it _will_ always trigger a re-render. With hooks, it seems that it does call twice only (though I'm not sure why, don't know as much about `useState`)

Comment: @Chris yes I meant useState, my mistake, typo..this.setState(class comp) will always trigger rerender while useState(functional) will not

Comment: @Jayce444 the hook variant uses some kind of shallow comparison

Comment: @SmailGalijasevic Yes, exactly. OP should've been more clear :)

Comment: @Chris you are right

Comment: I'm not a react expert but I don't think this is expected behaviour. You might get some more answers in the react github page

Answer (score 0):

A React component will update every time its `state` or `props` change. These two artifacts of a react component, can't be changed in `render` function or any functions called by `render`.

Also, you have to remember that you can't ever change the props of a component within the component itself. the props are passed from parent and cant be changed by the child.
But for the `state`, you can call `setState` in `onClick` functions or any other function outside the `render`, and any time you call the `setState`, your component will update its view.

After getting familiar with ReactJs, I suggest you use Redux for any kind of data manipulation and functionality. Here is a link to react-redux website: https://react-redux.js.org/

I hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

for updating the general usestate function:
const [initialState, setState] = useState(initialState)

`initialState` is the initial state of the component and

`setState` is the function that updates the initialState

for more information about useState Hooks in react:
Link:https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-react-hooks-usestate-6627120614ab

Answer (score 0):

react's `useState()` hook does shallow comparison before each time react updates the state using the update method provided by `useState()` hook.
In this [code sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-fog-riyg4) you can make below change to understand it clearly.

You can make below changes and try it.

1. `useState(0)`, make it like `useState({value:0})`.
2. `setNumber(1)`, make it like `setNumber({value:1})`.
3. And on line no 16 `{number}`, make it like `{number.value}`.

After making above changes to appComponent, your render will happen on every click of button, no matter if value is changed or not.

It is because `useState()` does shallow comparison before making update to the state.

And in case of objects, shallow comparison always returns false. because objects are compared using memory location and not by values inside them, during shallow comparison.

Comment: Have a look on 
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update